# Jmeter zabbix integration

Tags: jmeter, zabbix

In my current project we use jmeter for performance tests. To monitor server side metrics we plan to use zabbix. We tried using the perfmon metrics collector plugin that comes with jmeter , but unable to capture the graph results in headless execution mode. Being new to zabbix ,would like to know the steps to integrate zabbix with jmeter.Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

```
Two ways to do that.  
1- Client Side  
a) Write a script to execute your jmeter tests   
b) Make your way to execute this script periodically (cron(linux) or Scheduler(Windows))  
c) use the zabbix_sender (CLI) that comes with zabbix agent to send the data to Zabbix server.

2 - Server side (I prefer this way)

a) Write a script to execute your jmeter tests   
b) Configure this script on the agentd configurarion file like this

UserParameter=jmeter_stats[*], /etc/my_script_folder/jmeter_stats.py $1

jmeter_stats.py = Your script to execute jmeter tests
$1 = Parameters (if you have any)
jmeter_stats[*] = The Key you will configure on Zabbix

c) Create a new item on Zabbix server with type zabbix_agent and key jmeter_stat  

key:jmeter_stats[you_script_parameter_here]
```